# JavaScript form validation not working on all HTML fields

Tags: javascript, html, forms, function, validation

Hoping you can help, I am making a HTML form which uses JavaScript validation. The form validation works on Firstname, Surname and town. However, for some reason, it doesn't work on Frist line or Second line of address and also postcode and I am unable to tell why. Any help would be appreciated. Below is the HTML and JavaScript.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
<Title> In Class Test 5 </title>
<script src="RegisterCustomerValidation.js"></script>

<body> 
<h1> Working out the difference between today and your selected date </h1>

    <Form name="MyForm" >

<br> Please enter your first name:
<input type="text" id="Fname">  <br>         

Please enter your surname:
<input type="text" id="Sname">  <br> 

Please enter your first line of address 
<input type="text" id="FLINE"> <br>

Please enter your Second line of address
<input type="text" id="SLINE"> <br>

Please enter your City or Town
<input type="text" id="Town"> <br>

Please enter your postcode 
<input type="text" id="Pcode"> <br>

Please enter a email:
<input type="text" id="Email" size=15><br>  

Please enter your home number:  
<input type="text" id="Hnumber" size=15><br>

Please enter your mobile number     
<input type="text" id="Mnumber" size=15><br>

<button type="button" onclick="return f1()">Submit</button>
    </Form>  



</body>

</html>
```

My JavaScript:

```
function checkFName() {

var Fname = document.forms["MyForm"]["Fname"].value;
if (Fname == null || Fname == "") {
    alert("Name must be filled out");
    document.MyForm.Fname.focus();
    document.getElementById("Fname").style.border = '2px solid red';
    return true;
}
}

function checkSName() {
var Sname = document.forms["MyForm"]["Sname"].value;
if (Sname == null || Sname == "") {
    alert("Surname must be filled out");
    document.MyForm.Sname.focus();
    document.getElementById("Sname").style.border = '2px solid red';
    return true;
}
}

function checkTown() {
var Town = document.forms["MyForm"]["Town"].value;
if (Town == null || Town == "") {
    alert("Town must be filled out");
    document.MyForm.Town.focus();
    document.getElementById("Town").style.border = '2px solid red';
    return true;
}
}

function Pcode() {
var Pcode = document.forms["MyForm"]["Pcode"].value;
if (Pcode == null || Pcode == "") {
    alert("Town must be filled out");
    document.MyForm.Pcode.focus();
    document.getElementById("Pcode").style.border = '2px solid red';
    return true;
}
}
function checkFLA() {
var FLA = document.forms["MyForm"]["FLINE"].value;
if (FLA == null || FLA == "") {
    alert("First line of address must be filled out");
    document.MyForm.FLINE.focus();
    document.getElementById("FLINE").style.border = '2px solid red';
    return true;
}
}

function checkSLA() {
var SLA = document.forms["MyForm"]["SLINE"].value;
if (SLA == null || SLA == "") {
    alert("Second line of address must be filled out");
    document.MyForm.SLINE.focus();
    document.getElementById("SLINE").style.border = '2px solid red';
    return true;
}
}

function f1() {

alert("hello world");
if (checkFName(Fname)) {
    alert("First name must be filled out");
    document.MyForm.Fname.focus();
    document.getElementById("Fname").style.border = '2px solid red';
}


if (checkSName(Sname)) {
    alert("Surname must be filled out");
    document.MyForm.Sname.focus();
    document.getElementById("Sname").style.border = '2px solid red';

}


if (checkTown(Town)) {
    alert("Town must be filled out");
    document.MyForm.Town.focus();
    document.getElementById("Town").style.border = '2px solid red';

}

if (checkPcode(Pcode)) {
    alert("Surname must be filled out");
    document.MyForm.Pcode.focus();
    document.getElementById("Pcode").style.border = '2px solid red';

}
if (checkFLA(FLA)) {
    alert("First line of address must be filled out");
    document.MyForm.FLINE.focus();
    document.getElementById("FLINE").style.border = '2px solid red';

}
if (checkSLA(SLA)) {
    alert("Second line of address must be filled out");
    document.MyForm.SLINE.focus();
    document.getElementById("SLINE").style.border = '2px solid red';

}


}
```

Comment: You might want to have a look at AirBnB's JavaScript style guide.  https://github.com/airbnb/javascript

Comment: @whoacowboy how this helps the OP?

Comment: @Jordi see my answer below.

Comment: There are easier ways to do validations like this, but I DO encourage you to write code the way you are most comfortable with, and then over time your code will become more compact and cleaner, follow your inner FLOW, if you listen to others you will never come up with some new and original piece of code. Although if you plan to work for a large company then you need to follow conventions.

Answer (score 2):

I found it. Your program is choking on postal code.

You are checking -> if (checkPcode(Pcode))

But the correct name of the function is Pcode not checkPcode -> function Pcode() {

Edit. Yea, I just fixed FLA. Don't pass any arguments i.e. no FLA just if(checkFLA()) - I think it should work.

Comment: Double check all other functions and variables. Postal code works now but FLA not. Also check your alerts e.g. checkPcode alert says Surname must be filled out.

Comment: Thanks that helped, do you have any idea why FLA and SLA don't work?

Comment: Sorry, I also removed the argument FLA, because it is not really needed - I think that was the problem not changing names.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a number of errors around case sensitivity. JavaScript is a case sensitive language so `Fname` and `fname` are completely different.

It is a good practice to decide on a naming convention and stick with it.

camelCase is a good idea <s>although i just put everything to lower case for expediency</s>.

AirBnB has a [style guide](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript) that is a good place to get an idea of cleaner ways to write code.

I also really like **JavaScript: The Good Parts** by [Douglas Crockford](http://javascript.crockford.com/).

**html**

```
<h1> Working out the difference between today and your selected date </h1>

<form name="myForm" id="myForm" action="">
    <br>Please enter your first name:
    <input type="text" id="fName" />
    <br>Please enter your surname:
    <input type="text" id="sName" />
    <br>Please enter your first line of address
    <input type="text" id="fLine" />
    <br>Please enter your Second line of address
    <input type="text" id="sLine" />
    <br>Please enter your City or Town
    <input type="text" id="town" />
    <br>Please enter your postcode
    <input type="text" id="pCode" />
    <br>Please enter a email:
    <input type="text" id="email" size="15" />
    <br>Please enter your home number:
    <input type="text" id="hNumber" size="15" />
    <br>Please enter your mobile number
    <input type="text" id="mNumber" size="15" />
    <br>
    <button type="button" id="submitButton">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var form1 = document.forms["myForm"];
var submitButton = document.getElementById("submitButton");

function validateForm() {
    checkTextField('fName', "Name must be filled out");
    checkTextField('sName', "Surname must be filled out");
    checkTextField('fLine', "First line of address");
    checkTextField('sLine', "Second line of address");
    checkTextField('town', "Town must be filled out");
    checkTextField('pCode', "Postal Code must be filled out");
    checkTextField('email', "Email must be filled out");
    checkTextField('hNumber', "Home number must be filled out");
    checkTextField('mNumber', "Mobile number must be filled out");
}

function checkTextField(fieldName, message) {
        field = form1[fieldName];
    if (field.value === null || field.value === "") {
        alert(message);
        field.focus();
        field.style.border = '2px solid red';
    }
}
```

[See JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/whoacowboy/q4n7g9vg/3/)

**EDIT**
Updated code and sample to camelCase (it is a good idea).

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of mistakes you are doing in javascript code

1. calling as `checkPcode(Pcode)` actual function name `Pcode()`
2. no need to add `FLA` as parameter in  `if (checkFLA(FLA))` use `if (checkFLA())`
3. no need to add `SLA` as parameter in `if (checkSLA(SLA)` use `if (checkSLA())`